# Vue i18n TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I try to use `vue-i18n` in `ts` file of a component like this:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  readonly i18nTitle = this.$t('translation.key');

  //...
}
```

But I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined stackoverflow

This error only occurs when I try to use `i18n` in the `ts` file but it works fine when I use it in the `html`.

My configuration of `i18n` is really basic:

```
// i18n/index.ts
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';
import fr from './translations/fr.json';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

export const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'fr',
  fallbackLocale: 'fr',
  messages: {
    fr,
  },
});

// maint.ts
import { i18n } from './i18n';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  i18n,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>',
});
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing a bit I saw that it can work if I use a getter.

This is how I translate texts from the `ts` file:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  get i18n() {
    return {
      title: this.$t('translation.key');
    };
  }
}
```

And use it in the `html` like this:

```
<h1>{{i18n.title}}</h1>
```

Comment: This is the correct solution because using a computed property will ensure that the translation updates automatically if the language is changed.